# Add, subtract and compare compressed integers

Tags: c++, arrays, bit-manipulation

I need to do substantial simple algebras on equisized arrays of small integers. The operations consist of only three kinds: (i) add arrays and (ii) subtract arrays element-wisely, and (iii) compare if all elements in one array are no less / greater than their counterparts in another.

To boost cache locality and computing speed, I cram the small integers of every array bit-by-bit into a certain number of 64-bit integers. The number of 64-bit integers for use is determined by numbers of bits assigned to array elements. Let `a[j]` denote an array element. My design of bits for `a[j]` consists of (i) **bits that can hold the largest absolute value `a[j]` could hit during computation**, (ii) a sign bit, and (iii) a bit on the sign bit's left. The leftmost bit holds the possible carry from the right and gets zeroed after addition or subtraction.

Below is a toy example of adding, subtracting and comparing two 64-bit integers, each of which includes five small integers: the first 10 bits, the next 5 bits, the next 10 bits, the next 13 bits, and the next 20 bits. The rest bits are useless and set to 0.

```
// leftmostBitMask = 
// 0b0111111111011110111111111011111111111101111111111111111111000000
//   ^         ^    ^         ^            ^                  
// leftmost


std::size_t add(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, std::size_t leftmostBitMask)
{
  return (x + y) & leftmostBitMask;
}


std::size_t minus(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, std::size_t leftmostBitMask)
{
  return (x - y + ((~leftmostBitMask) << 1)) & leftmostBitMask;
}


bool notAllGreaterEqual(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, std::size_t leftmostBitMask)
{
  // return (minus(x, y, leftmostBitMask) & (leftmostBitMask >> 1)) == 0;
  return (x - y) & ((~leftmostBitMask) >> 1);
}
```

My algorithms seem complex, especially the comparison function. Are there any faster solutions?

Thanks!

BTW, SIMD is not what I am describing. My question is one lower level of optimization than SIMD.

More background: the idea serves a quite complex search algorithm in multidimensional space. We observed large differences between magnitudes of values in different dimensions. For instance, during computing an important 6-dimensional test case, one dimension could reach 50000 in absolute value yet all the others fall well below 1000. Without integer compression, each object requires a 32-bit array of size 6, while integer compression reduces the dimensionality to 1 (64-bit integer). Such reduction prompts me to think about cramming integers..

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Do you expect _really big_ sets of numbers?

Comment: @Chad  Yes, kind of. It's a search algorithm in multidimensional space

Comment: Performance issues of a working code are in the scope of [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I really doubt that operations on integers of variable size would be any better than those on an array of uint32_t's. Your example only improves compaction by 50% but have increased the operations required by more than triple I'd say.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Thank you for the comment, it is a toy example. Usually it can compact 5-7 integers in my scenario. The bigger problem is cache locality. Time differences between the algorithm solving a 3-dimensional problem and a 6-dimensional problem is large... and I just modified the example, making it compress 5 integers

Comment: You should profile your compression with bit twiddling vs. without the bit twiddling.  Often, the bit manipulating takes away any speed advantages with the compression.  Let the processor do its magic with its word size.

Comment: Rather than compression, try optimization.  Set you compiler's optimization for maximum for speed.  Next, organize you data for data cache optimization.  Also, try loading up many temporary variables from the array, then process them.  This will take advantage of the processor's caching ability.  If declare the temporary variables as `const`, the compiler may be able to place them into registers which will increase performance.

Comment: The idea here is to write your code so that the compiler can perform the best optimizations.  For example, consider loop unrolling.  If you code for loop unrolling, the compiler may be able to emit instructions for parallel processing.

Comment: Picture a pipeline of low level operations.  You want to design so that the operations are continuously flowing at the highest speed.  For example, when a subtraction operation is ready, the operands should be available (before the operation takes place).  Literally, prepare the food to feed the pipeline, before the pipeline needs the food.

Comment: Lastly, Profile.  Profiling will analyze the code and return performance metrics.  Focus your efforts on the sections of code that occupy the most time.  This is where you will reap the most profit.  Also, look at the assembly code generated by the compiler; use it as a base of understanding.  Re-code your function so that the compiler generates the optimal assembly language.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you for sharing your valuable experience. We have been working on the problem for some time and most of your suggestions have been tried. Integer compression is the last thing I want to test and has not been implemented. Indeed the performance is still in question. I come to stackoverflow thinking maybe somebody had done something similar before :)

Comment: By the way this is called SWAR, so now you have something to search for. There is a substantial body of pre-existing work.

Comment: @harold Ah, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After careful thought and comprehensive simulations, algorithms listed in the question turn out largely over-engineered. The leftmost bit for receiving carry is unnecessary. The code below works:

```
// signBitMask = 
// 0b1000000000100001000000000100000000000010000000000000000000000000
//   ^         ^    ^         ^            ^                  
// sign bit


std::size_t add(std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
{
  return x + y;
}


std::size_t subtract(std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
{
  return x - y;
}


bool notAllGreaterEqual(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, std::size_t signBitMask)
{
  return (x - y) & signBitMask != 0;
}
```

The key factor here is that every comparison made on two arrays is AND-based. We require `notAllGreaterEqual()` returns true as long as one elemental integer in `x` is below its counterpart in `y`. At first glance, the solution above could hardly be true: What happens when one negative elemental integer is added to a positive counterpart and the result stays positive? There must be a carry over the sign bit. In this case isn't the successive elemental integer contaminated? The answer is yes, but **it does not matter**. Collectively `notAllGreaterEqual()` would still fully serve its purpose. Instead of thinking in bits, one can easily prove `notAllGreaterEqual()` correct with elementary algebra. Problems could come only if we want to recover the integer array from those 64-bit buffers.

Creating the 64-bit buffer consists of (i) casting integers to `std::size_t`, (ii) shift the integer by pre-computed bits, and (iii) adding shifted integers. If an integer is negative being shifted to the right, `1` must be padded on its left.